# How to add sample responses for Form inputs in FastAPI redoc documentation?

Tags: fastapi, redoc

I have the following request:

`@app.post("/api/add_profile", description = "Add your details here")`

`async def your_profile(name: str = Form(description = "Enter your full name"),`
   `intro: str = Form(description = "Write a short introduction, this  will be displayed to others"),`
   `age: str = Form()):`

`response = get_profile(intro = intro, name = name, age = age)`
    `return {"content":response}`

The `get_profile` function is generating a string output, I want to display a sample response in **redoc** documentation for this api. I have seen how it can be done for Pydantic models but how can I achieve this for forms?